# How to set the y axis in ggplot2 R for comparing machine learning models

Tags: r, machine-learning, ggplot2

I have a dataset of machine learning model accuracies that I am looking to compare as boxplots, however I can't figure out how to set the Y axis to be accuracy.

My data is the model's accuracies with each kfold of cross validation:

```
Model     1         2          3            4          5           6            7           8           9        10
LR  0.69047619  0.71428571  0.61904762  0.57142857  0.69047619  0.69047619  0.73809524  0.76190476  0.78571429  0.76190476
SVM 0.80952381  0.76190476  0.76190476  0.76190476  0.80952381  0.76190476  0.78571429  0.76190476  0.88095238  0.88095238
RF  0.73809524  0.61904762  0.52380952  0.61904762  0.73809524  0.71428571  0.73809524  0.71428571  0.88095238  0.71428571
GBM 0.83333333  0.83333333  0.73809524  0.73809524  0.78571429  0.83333333  0.80952381  0.80952381  0.88095238  0.85714286
MLP 0.85714286  0.80952381  0.80952381  0.76190476  0.78571429  0.83333333  0.76190476  0.92857143  0.92857143  0.85714286
Keras   0.9047619   0.85714286  0.80952381  0.85714286  0.83333333  0.78571429  0.88095238  0.92857143  0.88095238  0.92857143
```

I have tried:

```
accuracy <- c(0,1)
p <- ggplot(bxplt, aes(Model, accuracy))
p + geom_boxplot()

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): y
```

I feel like I must be missing something obvious but I can't find any other similar enough questions or resources with similar examples, any help would be appreciated.

```
dput(bxplt)
structure(list(Model = structure(c(3L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("GBM", 
"Keras", "LR", "MLP", "RF", "SVM"), class = "factor"), X1 = c(0.69047619, 
0.80952381, 0.73809524, 0.83333333, 0.85714286, 0.9047619), X2 = c(0.71428571, 
0.76190476, 0.61904762, 0.83333333, 0.80952381, 0.85714286), 
    X3 = c(0.61904762, 0.76190476, 0.52380952, 0.73809524, 0.80952381, 
    0.80952381), X4 = c(0.57142857, 0.76190476, 0.61904762, 0.73809524, 
    0.76190476, 0.85714286), X5 = c(0.69047619, 0.80952381, 0.73809524, 
    0.78571429, 0.78571429, 0.83333333), X6 = c(0.69047619, 0.76190476, 
    0.71428571, 0.83333333, 0.83333333, 0.78571429), X7 = c(0.73809524, 
    0.78571429, 0.73809524, 0.80952381, 0.76190476, 0.88095238
    ), X8 = c(0.76190476, 0.76190476, 0.71428571, 0.80952381, 
    0.92857143, 0.92857143), X9 = c(0.78571429, 0.88095238, 0.88095238, 
    0.88095238, 0.92857143, 0.88095238), X10 = c(0.76190476, 
    0.88095238, 0.71428571, 0.85714286, 0.85714286, 0.92857143
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Can you provide your data via the output of `dput(df)` where `df` is your dataframe?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried this and added it in

Comment: A boxplot may not be the ideal visualization. Points and perhaps a violin plot (see my answer below) will show your actual data far better than a boxplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reshape your dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key = "fold", value = "accuracy", -Model) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Model, accuracy)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Please indicate which packages the user would need to run this code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reflow your data to a long format. What you have now is a wide format.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

xy <- matrix(runif(3*10), nrow = 3, dimnames = list(letters[1:3], 1:10))
xy <- data.frame(model = c("a", "b", "c"), xy, check.names = FALSE)

xy <- gather(xy, key = iteration, value = value, -model)

ggplot(xy, aes(x = model, y = value)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

If you feel the points are overlapping, try `geom_jitter()` instead of `geom_point()`.